# VM User Login data - How can I monitor user login data from DC?

Tags: domain-controller

I would like to generate report or send email when someone logs in to any of Virtual Machine's under the Domain Controller server.

How can I do it? Some where I read that we should **Use WMI/ADSI to query each domain controller** but I am new to all this.

I do not want to use SCOM - System center. 
Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could achieve this.

Personally, using Windows Server 2012 R2, I would add an action to Event ID 4624 to trigger either an alert or email to any address.

Comment: I do not want to track from local VM, I want to track from domain controller.

Comment: You could do it remotely from the DC via MMC/eventvwr. I am not sure there is a more efficient way.